# Docker failed to start service utility VM with LCOW on windows server 2019

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I try to run a Docker container on a fresh windows 2019 machine but on pulling it I get following error message after a night long waiting:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: failed to register layer: failed to start service utility VM (applydiff d3d444b7e4622ad1fed86aca20a57e5fec56d756feced70ef51bfeb0eb85aee5): container d3d444b7e4622ad1fed86aca20a57e5fec56d756feced70ef51bfeb0eb85aee5_svm encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: A connection could not be established with the container or virtual machine. (0xc0370108) extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"d3d444b7e4622ad1fed86aca20a57e5fec56d756feced70ef51bfeb0eb85aee5_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"bootx64.efi"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help'.
```

The windows runs under VMWare(V6.7 U3) where virtualization is enabled.
I tried the same thing with a virtual machine from azure which was working great. Can it be a problem with VMWare(V6.7 U3)? Do we need to activate the something more then the hardware virtualization flag?

I used following commands:

```
1. Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart 
A Reboot will happen 
2. Install-Module DockerProvider 
3. Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerProvider -RequiredVersion preview 
Reboot your machine manual once again. 
4. [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine") 
5. Restart-Service docker 6. docker run --name am-redis -p 6379:6379 --memory="4g" -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.10.0-ee-preview-3
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
 LCOW:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Standard
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 16GiB
Name: SV000034
ID: SBES:OFCG:TVZH:LO3Z:FPYQ:CQ3G:OEOP:JAYB:TGZA:VW35:SIYE:S7BK
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-3
 API version:  1.33
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   1649af8
 Built:        Fri Oct  6 17:52:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.10.0-ee-preview-3
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   b8571fd
 Built:        Fri Oct  6 18:01:48 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

[image: VMWare settings]