# Problem with Docker on Windows Server 2019: not running Linux containers

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2019

I was trying to install Docker on a fresh Windows Server 2019 using [this guide](https://blog.foldersecurityviewer.com/how-to-install-docker-and-run-docker-containers-on-windows-server-2019/) (other guides seem to use the same procedure).

**NB**: I was given a Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V installed, but *with no virtual machine*.

My installation commands were:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All -NoRestart
Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools -IncludeAllSubFeature
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
Restart-Computer –Force
```

And then:

```
Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Which returns an error:

```
Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "WinContainerHost".
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtens ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (WinContainerHost:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
```

Now, my first question is: what is `WinContainerHost`? Who did create it? I cannot see it in my Hyper-V Management Console.

Nevertheless, I try to go on with the Docker installation process:

```
Install-Module DockerProvider
Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerProvider -RequiredVersion preview
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(“LCOW_SUPPORTED”, “1”, “Machine”)
Restart-Service docker
```

After the process, typing `docker --version`, I get:

```
Docker version 17.10.0-ee-preview-3, build 1649af8
```

It seems that Docker is installed. I then try to launch a container with:

```
docker pull nginx:latest
```

which results in:

```
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
33847f680f63: Extracting [==================================================>]  27.15MB/27.15MB
dbb907d5159d: Download complete
8a268f30c42a: Download complete
b10cf527a02d: Download complete
c90b090c213b: Download complete
1f41b2f2bf94: Download complete
failed to register layer: failed to start service utility VM (applydiff 8f46920b86bdcdab20b89a73c657f59c52f0271fd2fa27bf87bb875c55c11f7a): 
container 8f46920b86bdcdab20b89a73c657f59c52f0271fd2fa27bf87bb875c55c11f7a_svm encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a 
Windows system call: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed. (0xc0370102) extra info: {"SystemType"
:"container","Name":"8f46920b86bdcdab20b89a73c657f59c52f0271fd2fa27bf87bb875c55c11f7a_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath"
:"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"bootx64.efi"},"ContainerType":"linux",
"TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}
```

My intuition tells me that the problem is with the `Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`, but I cannot find a way to solve it.

Could someone please give me more insight on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this new Windows Server 2019 server a VM? if so is it Hyper-V, VMware etc. ? Did you setup [Virtualization-based Security](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-CE292D3F-D4AC-4607-B262-DE19CE6E9F6B.html)

Comment: The Windows Server 2019 is a VM. I guess that it is a VMWare ESXI machine. Thanks for the hint, I am gonna check if Virtualization-based Security is enabled.

Comment: I think the vm track is a red herring. On a windows server 2016 with 17.10.0-ee-preview-3 I have access to, there are no hyper-v vms involved. Get-VM returns nothing, and there are no vms listed in hyper-v manager.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305059/docker-failed-to-start-service-utility-vm-with-lcow-on-windows-server-2019?